# SharePoint Online 'Author' Property for Purged Accounts

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I'm performing an audit of SharePoint Online to find all of our sites, subsites, etc., but I'm hitting an issue related to sites created by people who have left the company and that includes myself.

```
> Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $SPWeb -Property Author
Get-PnPProperty : User cannot be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPProperty -Connection $PnPConn -ClientObject $SPWeb -Property A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPProperty], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.EnsureProperty
```

This is what appears when I try to view the property.

```
> $SPWeb.Author

Id Title LoginName Email
-- ----- --------- -----
```

I am a rehire so my old AD account was disabled and purged, and my new one has a different ID. This means when I attempt to get the Author property off a SharePoint site I hit this error. This will also happen for my counterpart who left in 2017, and others who may have been creating subsites prior to us restricting it.

This error tells me either the mapping exists in some place and when it tries to retrieve them it fails, or it's actually a null value and fails because it's trying to *retrieve* a null value.

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: My test result is same with you:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOWu4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOWu4.png) We could still see the author in the subsite site pages library.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzexY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzexY.png)

Comment: That property is visible but I don't see a way to be able to pull it from the CSOM at the site level, and if the homepage has ever been changed I don't think we can rely on it as the source of truth. I'll see if there's any other ways and report back, but thank you for at least confirming!